# Python: str split on repeated instances in single string

Tags: python

How can I split and remove repeated patterns from a string, such as?

```
# sample
s1 = '-c /home/test/pipeline/pipelines/myspace4/.cache/sometexthere/more --log /home/test1/pipeline2/pipelines1/myspace1/.cache/sometexthere/more --arg /home/test4/pipeline3/pipelines3/myspace3/.cache/sometexthere/more --newarg etc.'

# expected
expected = '-c sometexthere/more --log sometexthere/more --arg sometexthere/more --newarg etc.'

# attempt only yields last value rather than all
''.join([ s for s in s1.split('/.cache/')[-1] ])
```

Comment: can that leading `'-c '` be ignored from result? It seems to be optional argument, you could prepend it at the end if needed

Comment: It seems you'd better first `.split()` the whole chain (around spaces), then split each substring IF it contains `/cache/`.

Comment: You could just use a simple [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub). [`re.sub(r'[^ ]*?\/\.cache\/', '', s1)`](https://regex101.com/r/SxyZfc/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split your string around spaces, so all the relevant parts will be split afterwards:

```
s2 = ' '.join([part.split('/.cache/')[-1] for part in s1.split()])
```

Output:

```
'-c sometexthere/more --log sometexthere/more --arg sometexthere/more --newarg etc.'
```